# Magento 2 Get Category Layout Name

Tags: magento2, category

I want to apply some logic when displaying a category depending on the category layout.

The logic should be applied if the category has a custom layout applied i.e. **1 column**

I can get the category data i.e. name in my template with `$_category->getName()` how can I get the name of the layout currently applied to the category?

Is it also possible to detect the category mode i.e. products only, static block only etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

`$_category->getData('page_layout')` should give you the layout name.